# Tensorboard issues with loading graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am trying to get tensorboard to simply show me my computation graph with no other summaries generated.

I am using the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()

a = tf.add(1, 2,)
b = tf.multiply(a, 3)
c = tf.add(4, 5,)
d = tf.multiply(c, 6,)
e = tf.multiply(4, 5,)
f = tf.div(c, 6,)
g = tf.add(b, d)
h = tf.multiply(g, f)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("output", tf.get_default_graph())
    print(sess.run(h))
    writer.close()
```

Then in the command line, starting from the folder in which I have stored the "output" folder, I use the following command:

```
$: tensorboard --logdir = output/
```

Tensorboard however tells me that there is no graph....
Help would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the logdir parameter without spaces: `tensorboard --logdir=output/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program does not expect spaces between the equals character `=` in `--logdir = <logdir>`. You must either call Tensorboard like this:

```sh
tensorboard --logdir=output/
```

Or leave the `=` out entirely:

```sh
tensorboard --logdir output/
```